Change in object properties after change in access modifier
In my Student class, the variable is first set to:
public String name;

I access this in the other class named StudentUse class as follows:
Student s1 = new Student();
s1.name= "sarang";
System.out.println(s1.name);

It printed 'sarang'.
After this I changed the access modifier of the variable to:
private String name;

and tried to print the same object variable 'name' using the getter method.
System.out.println(s1.getName());

Why is it printing null and not 'sarang', even though it was set to a value 'sarang' before changing the access modifier?
If we change the access modifier of a variable in java, is the previous information about the object lost?

You can't change the access modifier in a running program (except if you do hot code replacement, which will likely re-initialize a bunch of stuff and I wouldn't depend on it for learning). So what code are you actually running after the change? That code alone defines what the variable value will be.

and variables (field, local) do only exist while the code is running, these are not preserved in-between runs unless saved/restored in some way (database, file, preferences, ...)

Please provide full code for Student and StudentUse to see how you implemented the methods and how you are using them.

by the way, how is the field being set from a different class (StudentUse) after changing it to private? That should not be permitted ... maybe better provide a [mre]

It all boils down to your getName method, which, based on your description probably looks like this:
public String getName() {
    return null;
}

whereas it needs to look like this:
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

When you changed the modifier for name from public to private you effectively prevented direct access to that data-member and you did well to do so.
getName is still public, so you can access name via getName, so you have a public getter that you can use to read a data member's value, even though the data member is private and it can only be referred to and changed inside the class. By changing something from public to private you do not lose it. You just invalidate direct access to it from the outside and that's a good thing, because you might want to do other things too when that member is being read or written, like logging the action or anything of the like and if you have getters and setters, then you already have neat support for whatever future things you want to embed into these actions.

I have noticed that this answer has been down-voted. I consider this answer to be correct, but if I'm wrong anywhere, I'm happy to improve upon it as long as I know what needs to be improved and why. Thanks!
